# Have Two Columns Side By Side With Border

Tags: html, css

I want two columns side by side, and have a border on them.  The issue I am facing is that as soon as I add a border the columns stack on top of each other.

What is the appropriate syntax to create the two equal side by side columns but with borders?

This is the HTML and CSS I am using :

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.tab {
  padding-right: 90px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding: 1em;">
    <h1>Evil T1000</h1>
    <div style="height: 60px;"></div>
    <h1><span class="tab">Current Span of Data:</span>YTD</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding:1em; border-top:0;">Column1</div>
        <div class="column" style="border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding:1em; border-top:0; border-left: 0;">Column 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS columns? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css `grid` is a very powerful, you can create table like structure with css.

[Css Grid article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding: 1em;">
    <h1>Evil T1000</h1>
    <div style="height: 60px;"></div>
    <h1><span class="tab">Current Span of Data:</span>YTD</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding:1em; border-top:0;">Column1</div>
        <div class="column" style="border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding:1em; border-top:0; border-left: 0;">Column 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code in your styling of `.column` :

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use b`ox-sizing: border-box` to **universal selector**(*)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.tab {
  padding-right: 90px;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div style="border:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding: 1em;">
      <h1>Evil T1000</h1>
      <div style="height: 60px;"></div>
      <h1><span class="tab">Current Span of Data:</span>YTD</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding:1em; border-top:0;">Column1</div>
          <div class="column" style="border:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:black; padding:1em; border-top:0; border-left: 0;">Column 2</div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```